# For GET web service , it is working fine in local and same code is not working in web logic server

Tags: spring-boot, weblogic, spring-annotations

For GET web service , while hitting the WebService in postman, able to retrieve data from local and same code is not working in web logic server.

Input data format : JSON
Output data format : JSON

For another WebService , which we are not providing input , able to retrieve data from weblogic server
whereas WebService which requires input data is throwing 400 error.

May be it is not able to read content type.

Could any one please suggest me on this.

Tried adding
produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE , consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE , consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE

tried these 2 content types in all 4 combinations.

Even this is not working

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the url that is called ?
You could also have less restrictions on the Media type to begin with and see if this works.

Could you share some of the code you used aswell as how you call it on postman ? Maybe we could troubleshoot it

Comment: URL and all is fine....could you please suggest which mediatype needs to be used for JSON input to work in weblogic server